# Swift 4 TIC SSL Trust Error

Tags: swift, ssl, ios11

i coded this example but use another server.

http://andrewmarinov.com/parsing-json-swift-4/

i will receive a Json file, but I get the error:
**TIC SSL Trust Error**
**SURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed**

I can't change anything on the server!

can I use some code in swift 4/IOS11 to fix it?
here is my changed Plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes i mean "Json", sorry

Comment: I am having same error.

Comment: If u have access to the server u can generate a self signed certificate and add it to your IIS . That worked for me!

Comment: ok i will try it.

Comment: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/  tip 4 solved my Problem. But you must send the certificate to your device and acxept ist as rootcertificate. I used IT only dir testing.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code, and they work for me

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
            completionHandler(.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
        }
        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
            let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you use this? my ViewController is a WebViewDelegate and not a URLSessionDelegate.
I load a URL in the webView and then I see the error TIC SSL Trust Error